# How to design batteryless circuits with power harvesting

Tags: power, rf, pcb-design, energy-harvesting

I'm designing a PCB with 
- Micro-controller
- Accelerometer
- WiFi/Bluetooth
- NFC

Is it possible to run this board without any external batteries. I was looking at power harvesting modules, assuming the chips are ultra-low power. From my understanding, NXP offers NFC chips with embedded power harvesting capabilities capable of powering low power MCU.

Appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Provide a link to the data sheet (pdf).

Answer (score 1):

Here is my guess regarding power harvesting: If you would make the power harvesting antenna reasonably large and have it always **right next to** a WiFi accesspoint or next to any other transmitter and these are operating 24/7 then yes, it can probably be done.

But for any practical application that you could place anywhere so not near to anything transmitting radio waves all the time: NO, there will not be enough energy available to do anything usefull.

You, like many others, are grossly overestimating how much energy you can "harvest" in a practical scenario. You also may want to have a look at [this video](https://www.google.nl/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjok4Pq4cnJAhXI_w4KHasxAcsQtwIIIzAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DP8s3Xjeg0sk&usg=AFQjCNHvErET8r04J9hqFDm9gADLDkKfyw&sig2=Cefa8cmKR9VZPqDOTp7omg).